# PHPMailer does not work while php mail() works

Tags: php, phpmailer

it's on the same server + same file
php native mail works:

```
        $to      = 'myaddress@outlook.com';
        $subject = 'the subject';
        $message = 'hello';
        $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

while PHPMailer does not, result of $mail->send() is true, but never receives the email

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->setFrom('fiwejfiwe@gmail.com');
        $mail->addReplyTo('fiwejfiwe@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress('myaddress@outlook.com');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mails test';
        $mail->Body = 'This is a plain-text message body';

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message sent!';
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried testing with the exact same data in both cases? This isn't a valid experiment because the content of the email data is different...so you can't say it's definitely PHPMailer which is at fault... instead your mail could be identified as suspicious by the recipient for a different reason (the From address being the most likely culprit, since it clearly doesn't match the server you're sending the mail from, and therefore looks like spam/spoofing)

Comment: Dont you need to create an email on your server to use PHPmailer? (could be wrong)

Comment: @Crimin4L only the same as you do to use mail()

Comment: Both are sending via your local mail server, so the answer will be in your mail server's logs.

Answer (score 0):

mystery solved, the Linux server has been configured to not accept a @gmail.com from address.

Comment: And rightly so. Don't send emails which pretend to be from an account they actually aren't.

Comment: Indeed, Google's SPF config means that any messages you send with a forged from address like that will quite rightly be rejected or marked as spam.